# Android- draw a line on touch - error on event

Tags: android, events

I am new to android development.. m trying to develop an app to draw a line to follow the finger.. m taking the help of example `TouchPaint` on Dev Guide .. m getting an error on 
events.. `getPaintModeForTool(event.getToolType(j), mode)` also on `event.getHistoricalAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_DISTANCE, j, i)`

here is the code

```
final int action = event.getActionMasked();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                /*|| action == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE*/) {
            final int N = event.getHistorySize();
            final int P = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < P; j++) {
                    paint(getPaintModeForTool(event.getToolType(j), mode),
                            event.getHistoricalX(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalY(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalPressure(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalTouchMajor(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalTouchMinor(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalOrientation(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_DISTANCE, j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_TILT, j, i));
                }
            }
```

what to do guys?

Comment: What kind of error? Please post the logcat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you are looking for is just a line to follow the user's touch here is a class I use for a signature capture. It just overrides dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) and from there it generates a path that follows the user's finger. It has a very nice feature that makes curves the path; you see if the users moves the finger fast the new and last even coordinates are quite far apart (including any historical value associated with the event) and you end up with a jagged path.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SignatureView extends View {

    private final String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private float mSignatureWidth = 8f;
    private int mSignatureColor = Color.BLACK;
    private boolean mCapturing = true;
    private Bitmap mSignature = null;

    private static final boolean GESTURE_RENDERING_ANTIALIAS = true;
    private static final boolean DITHER_FLAG = true;

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Path mPath = new Path();

    private final Rect mInvalidRect = new Rect();

    private float mX;
    private float mY;

    private float mCurveEndX;
    private float mCurveEndY;

    private int mInvalidateExtraBorder = 10;

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(GESTURE_RENDERING_ANTIALIAS);
        mPaint.setColor(mSignatureColor);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mSignatureWidth);
        mPaint.setDither(DITHER_FLAG);
        mPath.reset();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (mSignature != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mSignature, null, new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(),
                    getHeight()), null);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mCapturing) {
            processEvent(event);
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean processEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown(event);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            Rect rect = touchMove(event);
            if (rect != null) {
                invalidate(rect);
            }
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            touchUp(event, false);
            invalidate();
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            touchUp(event, true);
            invalidate();
            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    private void touchUp(MotionEvent event, boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Rect touchMove(MotionEvent event) {
        Rect areaToRefresh = null;

        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        final float previousX = mX;
        final float previousY = mY;

        areaToRefresh = mInvalidRect;

        // start with the curve end
        final int border = mInvalidateExtraBorder;
        areaToRefresh.set((int) mCurveEndX - border, (int) mCurveEndY - border,
                (int) mCurveEndX + border, (int) mCurveEndY + border);

        float cX = mCurveEndX = (x + previousX) / 2;
        float cY = mCurveEndY = (y + previousY) / 2;

        mPath.quadTo(previousX, previousY, cX, cY);

        // union with the control point of the new curve
        areaToRefresh.union((int) previousX - border, (int) previousY - border,
                (int) previousX + border, (int) previousY + border);

        // union with the end point of the new curve
        areaToRefresh.union((int) cX - border, (int) cY - border, (int) cX
                + border, (int) cY + border);

        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        return areaToRefresh;

    }

    private void touchDown(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        final int border = mInvalidateExtraBorder;
        mInvalidRect.set((int) x - border, (int) y - border, (int) x + border,
                (int) y + border);

        mCurveEndX = x;
        mCurveEndY = y;

    }


    /**
     * Erases the signature.
     */
    public void clear() {
        mSignature = null;
        mPath.rewind();
        // Repaints the entire view.
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isCapturing() {
        return mCapturing;
    }

    public void setIsCapturing(boolean mCapturing) {
        this.mCapturing = mCapturing;
    }

    public void setSignatureBitmap(Bitmap signature) {
        mSignature = signature;
        invalidate();
    }

    public Bitmap getSignatureBitmap() {
        if (mSignature != null) {
            return mSignature;
        } else if (mPath.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
            c.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            return bmp;
        }
    }

    public void setSignatureWidth(float width) {
        mSignatureWidth = width;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mSignatureWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getSignatureWidth(){
        return mPaint.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    public void setSignatureColor(int color) {
        mSignatureColor = color;
    }

    /**
     * @return the byte array representing the signature as a PNG file format
     */
    public byte[] getSignaturePNG() {
        return getSignatureBytes(CompressFormat.PNG, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @param quality Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small
     *            size, 100 meaning compress for max quality.
     * @return the byte array representing the signature as a JPEG file format
     */
    public byte[] getSignatureJPEG(int quality) {
        return getSignatureBytes(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality);
    }

    private byte[] getSignatureBytes(CompressFormat format, int quality) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getSignatureBytes() path is empty: " + mPath.isEmpty());
        Bitmap bmp = getSignatureBitmap();
        if (bmp == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            getSignatureBitmap().compress(format, quality, stream);

            return stream.toByteArray();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: great, please set this as the answer if that's what you want.

Comment: great code. one issue, the clear() method isn't working for me :/